# Keyboard Enter Key is not working wordpress edit post or create post

Tags: wordpress, text, wysiwyg

When i create or edit any post in the dashboard the enter key works fine with visual editor but when i switch to text editor tab the enter key does not work.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta i just installed the wordpress. I did not write any code.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score -1):

When you are inside the Visual editor tab, the enter key actually adds a 
 tag to your code, so when you look at it visually it will have the line break.

So in the visual editor, when you type:
First line of content
Second Line of content

the actual code for those lines are

```
first line of content
<br />
Second line of content
```

or

```
<p>First line of content</p>
<p>Second line of content</p>
```

The text editor tab shows you just the HTML for that content.  Inside HTML code things like spaces and line breaks don't matter.

```
In the text editor <br /> this will display as one line, but on the page it will be two lines as well.
```